# Expression trees: invoking a method with out or ref arguments

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, expression-trees

This code works in .NET4:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var fooExpr = Expression.Parameter( typeof( Foo ), "f" );
        var parmExpr = Expression.Parameter( typeof( int ).MakeByRefType(), "i" );
        var method = typeof( Foo ).GetMethod( "Method1" );
        var invokeExpr = Expression.Call( fooExpr, method, parmExpr );
        var delegateType = MakeDelegateType( typeof( void ), new[] { typeof( Foo ), typeof( int ).MakeByRefType() } );
        var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda( delegateType, invokeExpr, fooExpr, parmExpr );
        dynamic func = lambdaExpr.Compile();
        int x = 4;
        func( new Foo(), ref x );
        Console.WriteLine( x );
    }

    private static Type MakeDelegateType( Type returnType, params Type[] parmTypes )
    {
        return Expression.GetDelegateType( parmTypes.Concat( new[] { returnType } ).ToArray() );
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public void Method1( ref int x )
    {
        x = 8;
    }
}
```

This code does not (blows up with runtime error at dynamic callsite):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var fooExpr = Expression.Parameter( typeof( Foo ), "f" );
        var parmExpr = Expression.Parameter( typeof( int ).MakeByRefType(), "i" );
        var method = typeof( Foo ).GetMethod( "Method1" );
        var invokeExpr = Expression.Call( fooExpr, method, parmExpr );
        var delegateType = MakeDelegateType( typeof( void ), new[] { typeof( Foo ), typeof( int ).MakeByRefType() } );
        var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda( delegateType, invokeExpr, fooExpr, parmExpr );
        dynamic func = lambdaExpr.Compile();
        int x = 4;
        func( new Foo(), out x );
        Console.WriteLine( x );
    }

    private static Type MakeDelegateType( Type returnType, params Type[] parmTypes )
    {
        return Expression.GetDelegateType( parmTypes.Concat( new[] { returnType } ).ToArray() );
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public void Method1( out int x )
    {
        x = 8;
    }
}
```

How come? The only difference is use of ref vs. out argument.

Comment: Error is: "Delegate <OnTheFlyDelegateType> has some invalid arguments"... no further details, no inner exception.

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens if you use `ref` instead of `out` at the call site? Also, what happens if you declare a delegate-type with the right `out` etc signature, and try a static-typed compiled lambda?

Comment: Wow, odd... if I use 'ref' at the call site (and keep 'out' in the method declaration), that works. A bug?   Edit - on second thought, not a bug. Just odd that there's no explicit way to create an 'out' argument on a dynamically constructed delegate type. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 0):

A **Ref** argument will be managed by the CLR a classic variable that will just be Box (encapsulate into a object to managed to pass the element by reference) if this one is a value.

**Out** permits to have multiple output and will have more impact during the compilation process.

The expressions are compile in runtime but the "out" validity is check at the compile time.

By validity, i mean that the compiler ensure that the method **WILL ASSIGN** value to the **out** parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried changing

```
typeof(int).MakePointerType
```

instead of:

```
typeof( int ).MakeByRefType()
```

At the lines:

```
var parmExpr = Expression.Parameter( typeof( int ).MakeByRefType(), "i" );
var delegateType = MakeDelegateType( typeof( void ), new[] { typeof( Foo ), typeof( int ).MakeByRefType() } );
```

Regards,